# Boost 1.44.0 + VS2010 Private member error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost

I have a class declaration in Utils.h:

```
    class Utils {
 private:
     static boost::mutex outputMutex;
    };
```

In the cpp file:

```
boost::mutex Utils::outputMutex = boost::mutex();
```

I get:

```
Error 1 error C2248: 'boost::mutex::mutex' : cannot access private member declared in class 'boost::mutex'
```

If we look inside `boost/thread/win32/mutex.hpp` we see:

```
namespace boost
{   
    class mutex:
        public ::boost::detail::underlying_mutex
    {

    // ...       

    public:
        mutex()
        {
            initialize();
        }
```

Does anyone know what I'm missing here? It used to compile OK on a different machine with VS2008.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .cpp file should be:

```
boost::mutex Utils::outputMutex;
```

There's no need for an assignment. It will be constructed appropriately.

Comment: It isn't assignment, it's copy initialization.

Comment: This works. If I remember right (not sure) it needed the assignment in VS2008. Cheers :)

Answer (score 3):

What you have is copy-initialization, and is equivalent to:

```
boost::mutex Utils::outputMutex(boost::mutex());
```

Which calls the copy-constructor. However, `mutex` is noncopyable. Just let it default construct:

```
boost::mutex Utils::outputMutex;
```

Comment: to be honest, I was not quite sure since it was mentioned it worked before.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're declaring `Utils::outputMutex` twice, once in the class declaration and then again in the .cpp. Also, the second declaration is being assigned the "return value" of the constructor, which isn't possible. What happens if you remove the second declaration?

Comment: its static initialization/definition