# Using Boost mutex in two different classes

Tags: c++, boost-thread, boost-mutex

i am using boost mutex in MessageQueue class as a private member in the following method

```
 void MessageQueue::Dequeuee()
    {
Request rq(messageWareHouse.front().reqID,messageWareHouse.front().seq,
                                                        messageWareHouse.front().sMessage);
        while(true)
        {
            boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(qMutex);
            qCond.wait(lock);

    **reqCollection**.find(messageWareHouse.front().reqID)->second.addSegments(messageWareHouse.front().seq,
                messageWareHouse.front().sMessage );
                    }
    ....
```

reqCollection is a map

```
map<size_t, Request> reqCollection;
```

Inside Request when i try to initialize the mutex i am getting the below error

```
class Request
{

private:

    size_t RequestID;

public:
    boost::mutex qMutex;
    Request(size_t requestID,size_t seq, std::string sMessage);
    void addSegments(size_t seq, std::string sMessage);

};
```

as far as i searched this error in google [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9284352/boost-mutex-strange-error-with-private-member) the solution for the problem is stated as

> Place (smart) pointers for the mutex or the class containing the mutex

but does this mean i can only use one mutex variable in my whole project by passing pointers? Why boost is protecting the mutex

the error is

> Error 7   error C2248: 'boost::mutex::mutex' : cannot access private member declared in class 'boost::mutex'

Comment: You don't actually provide the error, is it the same as on the link you posted?

Comment: sorry i edited the post with error

Comment: I don't understand where is the Request structure used in the Dequee() method?

Comment: i edited reqCollection is a map

map<size_t, Request> reqCollection;

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983588/boost-1-44-0-vs2010-private-member-error

Comment: I dont want the mutex to be static, i need two different mutex for two different classes. but class MessageQueue has an instance of class Request. when i remove the instance the error goes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mutex can't be copied, it is a system resource, so if you have it in some class which get's copied, the compiler generated copy constructor is called, the compiler generated copy constructor tries to copy the mutex, but it's copy constructer is private. hence the error.

If you wan't a copy of the resource chances are you'de like a different mutex, so you would need to write you're own copy constructor. If you wan't the copied objects to share the mutex you can use shared_ptr.

Alternatively you might not want to copy the objects at all, then you can use `std::map< size_t, std::unique_ptr< Request > >` if you don't have std::unique_ptr use shared_ptr

Comment: This is a good explanation, but i am not getting few thing over and over again. Every where i read they are stating what you mentioned " the compiler generated copy constructor tries to copy the mutex, but it's copy constructer is private. hence the error", i don't get. in C# and Java this is not a problem, because MessageQueue and Request are 2 different classes so how the same Mutex could be copied?

Comment: I think the actual problem is when inserting Request into the map. This copies the request. It is clear to me now, that the alternative I gave you is what you need to use. p.s. Visual C++ errors regarding compiler generated constructors is usually not very helpful in pinpointing where the actual error is located.

Comment: Your correct that is where the problem is. As you said Visual C++ errors arnt that clear. I'll look in to it.

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice if you posted the line on which you are getting this compile error. But I strongly suspect you are trying to call the copy constructor of the boost::mutex class which (the constructor) is private.